# Ag-grid with custom Header containing SearchBox and Focus Problem

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to implement a Ag-grid Table with a custom Column Header which displays a SearchBox (simple Textbox) below the normal Column text. How can I achieve this type of table?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom header component via `headerComponent` in `columnDefs`. this is the code you need

`index.tsx`

```js
const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>(
// or const columnDefs =    
  [
    { field: 'name', headerName: "Name", 
    headerComponent: CustomHeaderComponent, 
    headerComponentParams: {
      displayName: "Name",
    }},
    { headerName: 'Age', field: 'person.age' },
    { headerName: 'Country', field: "country" },
  ]);
```

`CustomHeaderComponent.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';

// Pass props through headerComponentParams.
const CustomHeaderComponent = ({ displayName }) => {
  return (
    <div className="custom-header">
      <span>{displayName}</span>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Filter..."
        /> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default CustomHeaderComponent
```

In addition, the function to filter by input is already provided through [Quick Filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-quick/) in Ag-grid.

Have a look at my [demo code](https://plnkr.co/edit/zfo99unIMqwU5oJK?open=index.tsx&preview).